# How to call jquery's .find in a lazy fashion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration, lazy-evaluation

When using jquery to locate a set of elements in an XML DOM structure;

Using .find with a CSS query will result in a result that can be iterated, however jquery will return all the results at that time, which is slow and pauses my UI.

How do I instead iterate over the results in a lazy fashion?

I observed that there is a .first() method, however I can't find .next() in the documentation, what am I missing?

Comment: `I can't find .next() in the documentation` have you looked at the online documentation? http://api.jquery.com, also specific to next: http://api.jquery.com/next/ The online documentation is very very detailed and the search box provided there is also very good helping you find anything you might need.

Comment: `next()` and `prev()` will not perform a lazy query either, it requires that you already have a jQuery nodeset

Comment: Indeed, I want to have a 'lazy nodeset'.

Comment: Sounds like the actual problem is that you have an excessive number of elements on the page.

Comment: @Shmiddty: Maybe I do, that doesn't negate the question, I come from languages where I am used to lazy evaluation.

Comment: @Arafangion: JavaScript is a language propably different than the ones you are used to then. Checking out the mozilla documentation on JavaScrip: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript and the http://api.jquery.com documentation for jQuery would help in determining the capabilities of the language. In the jQuery documentation the section on [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)  should also be helpful in learning how to write efficient selectors and how to cache them to prevent long running traversal and repetition.

Comment: @Arafangion If you post a link to the query you're using and the HTML you're working against, we can better help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best suggestion is to contain your searches. Never run global queries. If at all possible, start your search from an element that you can retrieve by ID (to limit the number of nodes to traverse)

For example instead of the following

```
var infoList = $("a.query span.info")
```

Use

```
var container = $('#myCt');
var infoList = container.find('a.query span.info');
// OR more simply (but I'm not sure jQuery optimizes the query)
var infoList = container.find('#myCt a.query span.info')
```

Comment: This makes sense, in the absence of lazy evaluation, reducing the search size would be an alternative.

Comment: I don't think lazy evaluation is the right term. What you would need is deferred evaluation (using setTimeouts), so that the UI thread gets a chance to update while your search is being performed

Comment: That would be an alternative, I was using 'lazy evaluation' because I wanted the concept of: "If I want the first item, locate it, then stop looking.  If I want the next item, start looking for that..."

Comment: @Arafangion Even if `jQuery` had a way to do that, you'd still need to separate the calls to get the next element with `setTimeout` to avoid locking up the browser, but I do see what you mean...

Comment: A good point, however lazy evaluation would allow more naive selectors (Eg, with lazy evaluation, I could just work with the first 5 items in a result, rather than crafing a selector that only results in just those 5 items).  I'll have to focus more on writing better selectors.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and a [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) you can use to go to next or previous sibling in the DOM structure.

Comment: The methods exist, but they don't really help lazy querying. See my comment on the question

Comment: Thanks for those, I was looking at http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/filtering/ which didn't have .next(). (I'm still new to jquery), however @JuanMendes has the right interpretation of my question.

Comment: @Arafangion: Providing accurate selectors, caching the references and executing sub-searches on specific selectors is smart and efficient traversal and not an interpretation of lazy loading as far as I know but instead may be your only **alternative** given the language you are working with.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: That is also my impression.

Answer (score -3):

```
$(".class").each(function() {
//do code here
});
```

Comment: How is this better than `find`? Sincere question.

Comment: each iterates where the author's use of find() is getting all the elements first and causing his problem. "...however jquery will return all the results at that time, which is slow and pauses my UI."